# xml2struct cannot access element(s)

Tags: matlab

I try to use this:

[xml2struct](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28518-xml2struct)

when I use this xml:

```
<XMLname attrib1="Some value">
    <Element>Some text</Element>
    <DifferentElement attrib2="2">Some more text</DifferentElement>
    <DifferentElement attrib3="2" attrib4="1">Even more text</DifferentElement>
</XMLname>
```

I can create a struct:

```
test = xml2struct('C:\bla\bla.xml');
```

(tested it with class(test))

It looks like this:

test =

```
      Name: 'XMLname'
Attributes: [1x1 struct]
      Data: ''
  Children: [1x7 struct]
```

But I cannot access:

```
test.XMLname.Element.Text
```

I get:

??? Reference to non-existent field 'XMLname'.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tried it on R2010b and it works fine

```
>> data=xml2struct('bla.xml')
data = 
    XMLname: [1x1 struct]

>> data.XMLname
ans = 
             Element: [1x1 struct]
    DifferentElement: {[1x1 struct]  [1x1 struct]}
          Attributes: [1x1 struct]
```

Is it possible you have an older version of xml2struct somewhere on your matlab path? Make sure `which xml2struct` gives you the path you expect

Comment: I am currently using R2008a. Could this be the issue?

Comment: That's the only reason I can think of right now. But you could try and access the data you need using the `Children` field of the struct you have.

Comment: Quote the answer. I had the same problem, I've solved it downloading the new version from http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28518-xml2struct/content/xml2struct.m

Answer (score 1):

When I look at your question I see a structure like this

```
test =

      Name: 'XMLname'
Attributes: [1x1 struct]
      Data: ''
  Children: [1x7 struct]
```

and an attempt to read a non-existent component of the structure

```
test.XMLname.Element.Text
```

that is structure `test` does not have a component named `XMLname`.

Am I missing something obvious or are you ?

Comment: No you don't. It seems as if xml2struct does not transform things correctly. I believe it may have to do with my matlab version.